# Issue setting style offset-distance and offset-path for Safari iPad 8th v14.0

Tags: css, angular, typescript, svg, mobile-safari

As context, I'm developing a size selector, using a svg to draw a curve path, and using a div as a dot in the path.

In Safari iPad 8th v16.1 it looks like this:

[image]

But in Safari iPad 8th v14.0 it looks like this:

[image]

Inspecting the html, I noticed that the style for offset-distance and offset-path is not set to the "dot" div, due to that, it looks like this:

`<div _ngcontent-aes-c94="" dot-directive="" class="dot angle ng-star-inserted">`

When it must look like this:

`<div _ngcontent-ayx-c219="" dot-directive="" class="dot angle ng-star-inserted" style="offset-distance: 0%; offset-path: path(&quot;M 20 20 L 260 20 C 340 20 340 120 260 120 L 80 120 C 0 120 0 220 80 220 L 300 220&quot;);">`

The way how that element styles are set is this: (typescript language for angular)

```
      constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, private render: Renderer2) {}

      //...Some stuffs

      private renderDots() {
         const percentage = 100 / (this.sizes.length - 1);
         this.dots.forEach((d, index) => {
           this.render.setStyle(d.nativeElement,'offset-distance', `${index * percentage}%`);
           this.render.setStyle(d.nativeElement,'offset-path', `path('${this.path}')`);
         });
         this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me to understand why it is not working, and how could I fix it.

Thank you!

**Note: I'm using BrowserStack to test it in different devices.**

I'm trying to set offset-distance and offset-path style through typescript to a div, and I expect the same result for iPad Safari 14.0 that iPad Safari 16.1

Comment: [Not supported on Safari on iOS < 15.4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/offset-path)

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen, thanks for your quick response, do you have any suggestion about how I could get done an approach like this with something supported by that browser version or I would need to implement a completely different approach for this browser version, thanks!